# Goodness of fit test

Tags: normal-distribution, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I have the following exercise that shows $n=6$ numbers:

$$ 1.40, 1.55, 1.35, 1.50, 1.29, 1.64 $$

Is data normally distributed at the 5% significance level?

Surely $\overline{x} = 1.455$, $s=0.1315674732$ and $n_1 = \cdots = n_6 = 1$ but how can i continue?

Comment: I suggest that you post that question at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What have you tried to verify the hypothesis that the data is normally distributed?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).